# International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) chart handbook

Tags: ipa, resource-request

As a gift for a friend who is finishing a translatio degree I wanted to get a large IPA chart poster and would like to accompany it with a guide for it.
I have seen there is an [official handbook](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/content/handbook-ipa) but I don't know if it will be up to date with the chart, since the chart has been updated last year and the handbook's last edition is from 1999.

What are the recommended resources? I'm not looking for a specific format, a PDF which I could print and bind or a book available to buy would both do fine (of course low-budget options are preferred).

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been very little change to the IPA as a whole since 1999 and the Handbook is the latest of its kind, so its value as a reference has not diminished. But you might want to make sure your friend hasn't got it already.